# Have a reference to variable in a base class that updates in a child class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an example below where I reference self.attrs in self.properties in the base class. If I child class updates self.attrs like in the case of Child1, id like it to be that value when i unpack self.properties. If i do not change it, id like it to be whatever it was in the parent class. See below.

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attrs = {}

        self.properties = {
            "attrs": self.attrs,
            "method": self.parentMethod(),
        }

    def parentMethod(self):
        return "Parent Method"

class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.attrs = {"name": "Bob"}

        self.properties = {
            **self.properties,
            "method": self.childMethod(),
        }

    def childMethod(self):
        return "Child1 Method"

class Child2(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.properties = {
            **self.properties,
            "method": self.childMethod(),
        }

    def childMethod(self):
        return "Child2 Method"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method that looks like an instance variable, then you want a [property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work-in-python).

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attrs = {}

    @property
    def properties(self):
        return {
            "attrs": self.attrs,
            "method": self.parentMethod(),
        }

    def parentMethod(self):
        return "Parent Method"
```

Then a new dictionary will be constructed *when* `self.properties` is accessed, and it will always use the *current* value of `self.attrs`. Note that, with this approach, you *don't* want to set `self.properties` again in the child class; it will always reflect the current status of the class whenever referenced.